# angular 8 : Why the component is not loading?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular8

So I created an app with `angular-cli` . I have following structure in `src` dir.

`.
├── app
│   ├── app-routing.module.ts
│   ├── app.component.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   └── notifications
│       ├── notifications.component.css
│       ├── notifications.component.html
│       ├── notifications.component.spec.ts
│       └── notifications.component.ts
├── assets
├── environments
│   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   └── environment.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── main.ts
├── polyfills.ts
├── protocol.js
├── styles.css
└── test.ts`

Routes have following.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', component: AppComponent },
        { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent}
    ])
```

AppComponent has Html for the login page.
Once the form is submitted I redirect to `notifications` component with `[routerLink]="['/notifications']"`

Now I am expecting `<app_root></app_root>` in the index.html to be populated with `notifications-component.html`.

**First of all, is the assumption above right?**

I tried to change the selector in `notification-component.ts`
I tried putting `<app-notifications></app-notifications>` in `<app_root></app_root>`
I tried putting `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `<app_root>`, `app.component.html` and `notifications.component.html`. (Only `app.component.html` worked. but it is showing both HTMLs.)

**If the assumptions above is not right, how is it supposed to work?**

P.S.

***THANKS, EVERYONE FOR PROMPT RESPONSE.***

I know all of your answers are right, but I could only accept one answer.

Comment: In your `app.component.html` did you try `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and your login html ?

Comment: It is not the solution, but, your <router-outlet> must go in appComponent, you should not create a route that directs you to the appComponent, you get an infinite loop, appComponent is always loaded

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A couple of changes are required to your approach:

1. Add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the `app.component.html` file.
2. Create another component for login ( eg. `LoginComponent` )
3. Update route

   ```
      RouterModule.forRoot([
       { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent },
       { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent }
      ])],
   ```

*Also it's not recommended to use the home path for login, you can change the url to /login and re-route if it's not authenticated.

Have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfhxek.

Answer (score 2):

AppComponent should be your app's root component, with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside (and possibly little or nothing more). Don't have a route leading there, it's the one component that'll always be rendered.

Create a separate component handling login (`LoginComponent` for example), and have routes like:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent}
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'login'},
    ])
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my problem was case sensitivity. The mistake that new developer like me could make, is path name case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing what you want would be like this

1. Create a new component for login
2. In the `app.component.html` place the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
3. Change your routing module this way:

   RouterModule.forRoot([
           { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
           { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent}
       ])

Answer (score 1):

Your `RouterModule.forRoot` cannot have the `AppComponent`. This component is bootstrapped in the `main.ts`.

You say you added the login html inside your `AppComponent`. This is not correct, you should move this to a separate component, `LoginComponent`. Once you've done this you can update your `app.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You can obviously add extra stuff here which will always be visible, like navigation or a footer.

You should then update your routes to this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent}
]);
```

Comment: The route configuration you have in your post will ALWAYS route to LoginComponent. Either add `pathMatch:'full'` or move it down.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren I disagree [check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpmj17?file=src/app/app.component.html), however I guess you should always have a fallback redirect if you have an unmatched route, or have it route to a 404 page. Anyways, a pathMatch full is not necessary in my answer

Comment: It seems you are correct. According to the documentation the above example shouldn't work, but it clearly does. It might be a flaw in the documentation or the example is too simple to reveal the real issue. https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren This is only necessary if there is a redirect on that empty path :) "Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop."

Answer (score 0):

I just understood that the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` line in app.component.html must be the only line in that file, and I moved all my app.component.* code to a new component I called 'home.component.*', and routed to 'home' from 'login' once login was successful. This worked well for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).